# How to solve Mysql PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

Tags: forms

I have created form to add general information about daily work. When I submit this form it will give me following error. Please help me. I have checked my `setting.php`. There prefix is `drup_`

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'i1164525_drup1.drup_drup_Detailstable' doesn't exist: INSERT
>   INTO {drup_Detailstable} (Username, Email_Id,
>   Work_Location,Team_size,Total_hours,Date,Description,Verified) VALUES
>   ('admin','swap@mm.com','abc','1','20','12/12/2014','Test','Not
>   Verified'); Array ( ) in eval() (line 43 of
>   /home/csrdiarycom/public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d
>   code).

```
 <form name="form" method="post" action=''<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <label>Work Location</label>
 <input type="Text" name="location" value=""/>
 <label>Individual/ Number of people</label>
 <input type="Text" name="numberofpeople" value=""/>
 <label>Date</label>
 <input type="Text" name="date" value=""/>
 <label>Total Time spend by You/Team(In Hours)</label>
 <input type="Text" name="Totalhours" value=""/>
 <label>Your Experience</label>
 <textarea row="5" maxlength="200" cols="30%" name="comment">Type here</textarea>
 <input type="Submit" name='Submit'/></form>
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
 {
   $location=$_POST['location'];
   $numberofpeople=$_POST['numberofpeople'];
   $Totalhours=$_POST['Totalhours'];
   $date=$_POST['date'];
   $comment=$_POST['comment'];
   db_query("INSERT INTO {drup_Detailstable} (Username, Email_Id, Work_Location,Team_size,Total_hours,Date,Description,Verified) VALUES ('$e','$e','$location','$numberofpeople','$Totalhours','$date','$comment','Not Verified')")->execute();
  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";
  }}
  ?>
```

Comment: Looks like the drup_ prefix is automaticly added to your query. Now it is looking for the table drup_drup_Detailstable

Comment: So can i replace drup_Detailstable to Detailstable

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'drup_' prefix from your db_query call. Since you define a prefix in settings.php, using {Detailstable} will automatically add the prefix on lookup.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done from phpmyadmin or drush.

**drush sql-cli**

> mysql> DELETE FROM field_config WHERE field_name =
>   [‘field_DELETED_FIELD’];
>
> mysql> DELETE FROM field_config_instance WHERE field_name =
>   [‘field_DELETED_FIELD’];

Clear cache after deleting  i.e. drush cc all